Setting dbt_valid_from to NULL to mean beginning of time
When using DBT snapshot it is documented that dbt_valid_to=NULL means that the record is the currently active or most recent record in the timeline.
One would then assume that setting dbt_valid_from=NULL would mean that a record is the first record in the timeline and valid from beginning of time.
However, even though the dbt_valid_from field is nullable in the schema, when you set it to NULL subsequent snapshots break because modified rows are no longer detected or inserted.
Is this a bug, or am I unaware of how snapshots are supposed to work?

here is a pretty good explanation of what dbt is doing under the hood in snapshots: https://sarathd.medium.com/slowly-changing-dimensions-using-dbt-snapshots-2a46727f0d39

Based on the discussion here, we resorted to not fiddling with DBTs snapshot management, but instead making the logic explicit in the models.
We're now using the following macro to add a version column to downstream models:
{% macro snapshot_version_column(unique_key) %}
(row_number() over (
  partition by {{ unique_key }}
  order by dbt_valid_from nulls first
))
{% endmacro %}

This can then be used as you like to further implement the desirable logic. One being to add a null real_valid_from column for the first records in the timeline:
{% macro snapshot_add_real_valid_from(ref, unique_key, initial_valid_from) %}

with versioned as (
  select
    {{ snapshot_version_column(unique_key) }} as version,
    *
  from
    {{ ref }}
)
select
    *,
    case when version = 1 then {{ initial_valid_from }}
    else dbt_valid_from end as real_valid_from
from versioned

{% endmacro %}

